# Why is there a watermelon there?

Tags: buckaroo-banzai

In the ridiculous (and great) film *The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the 8th Dimension*, there are many questions to be asked. The movie asks one of them itself: "Why is there a watermelon there?" I am referring to a scene in which New Jersey, played by Jeff Goldblum, notices a watermelon between two panels. The scene is quite funny, and the question is never answered. Are there in- and out-of universe answers to this question, besides "It's just a joke?"

Comment: To my surprise, I got curious, and there's a [mention](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/YMMV/TheAdventuresOfBuckarooBanzaiAcrossThe8thDimension) that it was a prank to piss off an exec... and a litmus test to see if any execs still paid attention.  I don't see an original source on that though.  Some random googling says the source was in the DVD commentary.

Comment: http://www.aintitcool.com/node/11158 - Scene was inserted to check if the producer was still watching the dailies.

Comment: ["What exactly is the Watermelon doing there?"](http://www.figmentfly.com/bb/faq1.html)

Comment: *"One crucial question... what is that watermelon doing there? Well, we were extremely concerned that Begleman was gonna shut the movie down. Every time we did something we were proud of, he would hate it. He really hated Buckaroo's red glasses, he said, "a hero doesn't wear red glasses." He hated that there was a certain anarchic logic that he couldn't get onboard with. So the watermelon is there just to see if he had gotten so disgusted with us that he wasn't watching our dailies anymore."*

Comment: *"And it proved to be true, because early on in the movie, he would've shut it down for that little moment of the watermelon. But, he'd given up in despair."* - http://www.figmentfly.com/bb/tv10.html

Comment: Gregory J. Smalley, of 366 Weird Movies, has the explanation that there's a watermelon between those plates because a grape wouldn't show up on camera. http://366weirdmovies.com/112-the-adventures-of-buckaroo-banzai-across-the-eighth-dimension/

Comment: For the same reason there was a cow in Walter Bishop's laboratory.  To underscore the "mad scientist" vibe.

Answer (score 2):

There was a fan club for a while that said the in-universe reason was to create a watermelon that could be air-dropped into famine areas and provide a combination of food and "water".

Comment: Could you provide a quote or something? Maybe via waybackmachine of their old website or something?

Comment: It was from a hard copy that was sent out to the "Blue Blaze Irregulars" before the internet. It's buried in a box somewhere so not going to be able to provide a reference.

Comment: Should have googled a little more... http://www.worldwatchonline.com/ww1-apr86.zip  Page 16